# Problem with titlesec package

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I'm helping my girlfriend with her thesis - she wants to eliminate the gap between section headings and the following text.  I tried loading the titlesec package, but I get an error if I do:

```
Error: Entered in horizontal mode.
```

I've traced the error to the section heading definition in the custom class file we're using.  It specifically seems to be the call to #1, but that is pretty crucial...!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{mwe}

\setlength{\parskip}{2ex}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{1.0ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}{-\parskip}

\begin{document}

\section*{Abstract}
I want this text to be up against the section heading

\end{document}
```

And this is the problematic excerpt from the cls:

```
\newcommand{\sect@format}[1]{%
  \noindent\protect{%
    \@tempdima=\hsize
    \parbox{0.99\@tempdima}{%
      \smallskip\section@font%
      \textcolor{\section@colour}{#1}\smallskip
    }%
  }%
}%
\sectionfont{\sect@format}
```

The class file is one I was given for own thesis some time ago, and not something that desperately needs to remain unaltered if there is a better way.

Comment: Just noticed that the cls file contains the following caveat: `% We have to do it this way because pdflatex sometimes screws up the colour of text if we do it the sensible way.`

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is the .cls file really used?

Comment: Thanks. It's a Cambridge University Engineering Department one, but not the one that can be found online.  Not sure where I can put the whole thing - hence the extract.  I've managed to recreate mostly with the titleformat command now - can't get the colour to change though, and haven't found the right option to put the section number in the margin as was done by the above.

Comment: You could use, if allowed by your uni to make it public, e.g. [pastebin](http://pastebin.com)

Comment: It's not a university affiliated one, AFAIK - https://pastebin.com/ZGM7Puwi

Comment: [I've commented out the problematic bits as I was experimenting - hadn't realised] Line 134 on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I haven't solved the conflict between the cls file and titlesec, *per se* - but I have managed to get what I want with the removal of the excerpt quoted above and the addition to the cls file of:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\selectfont\large\color{CambridgeDeepBlue}}{\llap{\hspace* .   {-\mylen}\thesection\hfill}}{0em}{}[]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{1.0ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}{-\parskip}
```